# Android image upload by JDBC

Tags: android, jdbc

How to upload an image with binary to mssql server using JDBC. I am getting an error like
" java.sql.SQLException: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

```
con = ConnectionHelper(un, password, db, ip);
//decoded = "image converted in binary value"
String commands = "Insert into sub_flupld(uuid,file_name,file_data,file_type,uploaded_data,report_date,file_conttype) values ('chetansoppin','test.jpg','"+decoded+"','JPG','"+mydate+"','"+mDisplayDate.getText().toString()+"','"+ spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "')";

PreparedStatement preStmt = con.prepareStatement(commands);
preStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert byte-array into column for string type. Can you add the table schema into which you are trying to insert ?

Comment: column datatype is var binary(max)

Comment: You are using your `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. You should **not** be injecting the column values into the SQL command text. Instead, you should be using parameter placeholders to perform a parameterized query.

Comment: i tried with parameter like ? instead of passing byte value , and used preStmt .setBytes(2,decoded)  but fot error invalid parameter index 2

Comment: Please post the code with `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: String commands = "Insert into sub_flupld(uuid,file_name,file_data,file_type,uploaded_data,report_date,file_conttype) values ('chetansoppin@Healthcare','test.jpg','?','JPG','"+mydate+"','"+mDisplayDate.getText().toString()+"','"+ spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "')";
                // encodedImage which is the Base64 String

              //  Statement statement = con.createStatement();

                PreparedStatement preStmt = con.prepareStatement(commands);
                preStmt.setBytes(2,decoded);
                preStmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: Add you code in the question, not in comments

Comment: i added my question